# Firebase Android - Dont sync some fields to server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way not to sync particular field(s) back to the server, but will be persisted and managed locally by firebase.

For eg.

```
public class SomeFBData implements Serializable {
    private String contentID; 
    private ContentData contentData;
    private int localViewCount; //This should not be synced back to firebase server. But should be persisted locally
}
```

This is similar to `transient` keyword, which makes the field skip the Serialization, only that here the field will be persisted locally, but not synced remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify if you're using Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore, I'll answer for both.

For Realtime Database, there is an annotation called [Exclude](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude) (in package com.google.firebase.database) that you can put on member variables or getter/setter methods that will prevent the value from being serialized.

For Cloud Firestore, there is an annotation also called [Exclude](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Exclude) (in a **different** package com.google.firebase.firestore) that's used the same way.